# Android OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 57993496 byte allocation with 16764448 free bytes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to make my `count` variable synchronized for `get` and a private helper function for setting based on other members. Multiple threads are each calling `setCount()` as `deadlineNoteVisible` and `referencesAvailable` change.

With `synchronized` for just the `setCount()` method, things are fine, but when I add `synchronized(this)` to the `get()` call, I 
get:

```
OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 57993496 byte allocation with 16764448 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
```

Code (written in Kotlin):

```
var count: Int = 0
    // Why does adding synchronized here explode?
    get() = synchronized(this) { count }
    private set

private fun setCount() {
    synchronized(this) {
        count = 0
        if (deadlineNoteVisible) {
            count += 1
        }
        if (referencesAvailable) {
            count += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Error reporting crash
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 57993496 byte allocation with 16764448 free bytes and 32MB until OOM
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:687)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:198)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
    at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:343)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
    at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:249)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a "crashlytics" crash handler that fired when an uncaught exception was thrown, and it's attempting to generate a 55MB string when printing the stack trace. Attaching a debugger that traps uncaught exceptions will at least let you identify the crash that's starting things off.

Comment: The `synchronized` method is probably a red-herring, it's just what caused a leaking application to get too large. Can you profile yoyr running app and find out what's using memory?

Comment: Why would you need to synchronize a read anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you've got a `StackOverflowError` because you're calling `getCount()` from `getCount()` unconditionally. I suppose it's just a typo and the code should be:

```
var count: Int = 0
    get() = synchronized(this) { field }
    private set
```

The `field` identifier here allows you to access a backing field of the property. You can read read more about backing fields [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields).